# IntelliJ IDEA doesn't recognize that my project is in git, has "N/A" for branch name

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I am expanding on work done by another developer, and was given their existing code base over sneakernet. I started working on my local machine before the Git repository for the project was set up. Now, after getting access to the repository, I've cloned the repository to my local machine, set up my feature branch, added my changes to that directory, and have pushed my changes to the origin.

However, when I switched back to IntelliJ IDEA to continue working, it doesn't recognize that the project is now using Git. Where I would normally expect to see my branch name, it just says "N/A". How do I get IntelliJ to recognize that my project is a Git project now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem**

There are a few problems here that created the issue:

- The previous developer wasn't using IntelliJ IDEA, so there was no existing settings directory telling the IDE about the VCS setup
- The original project directory wasn't used, but was instead copied from, and the pulled directory became the new project root
- The original project directory wasn't under VCS, so IntelliJ didn't know to even look for the branch name

**The fix**

In the toolbar menu, select `VCS > Enable Version Control Integration`, and in the popup window, select `Git`. Now all of the Git features you would expect to see are working.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is changing manually the vcs.xml file from the .idea folder.

Should be something like :

```
  <component name="VcsDirectoryMappings">
    <mapping directory="" vcs="Git" />
    <mapping directory="$PROJECT_DIR$" vcs="Git" />
  </component>
```

Answer (score 1):

If IntelliJ is in safe mode, version control is disabled.

Trust the project and version control will show up.

Comment: No, IntelliJ didn't know about version control at all. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55069022) explains exactly what was wrong and how I fixed it.

Comment: This was my case when I import project but is not trusted. Once I tried to build the project first time Idea asked me whether it should trust this project or not. After I clic "trust" button, Git menu item immediately appeared at the top of Idea.